# 404 -resource under sub-directory not found in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am able to access a resource(say test.html) only when it is directly under WebContent in eclipse.If i place it in WEB-INF or WEB-INF/jsp the IDE shows error 404-requested resource is not available.

```
 http://localhost:8080/MyApp/test.html (This works when test.html is under WebContent and not any of it's subdirectory)
```

When it is in WebContent/WEB-INF
Right click-run takes to the below URL which shows 404-resource not available

```
       http://localhost:8080/MyApp/WEB-INF/test.html
```

How do i access it by placing "test.html" in WEB-INF or WEB-INF/jsp?

All configurations are default with no restrictions specified in web.xml and using Tomcat 7 as the web server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent access to specific files. You cannot access /WEB-INF/ directory from outside the server itself. If you want to create subdirectory create them under

WebApp/
-index.jsp
-YourSubdirectory/
--test.jsp

test.jsp can be accessed via localhost:8080/MyApp/YourSubdirectory/test.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Files at WEB-INF directory cannot be accessed directly from browser. This is the basic restriction.

However content of this directory could be accessed at application level. Web container provides such opportunity.

For example, if you using SpringMVC, you can map some URL to the file at WIB-INF directory and it will work correctly.